# Relationship between kernel and homotopy kernel

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $R$ be a ring, and $C$ the category of $R-$modules (for instance, abelian groups) . We can consider the category $\text{Com}(C)$ of complexes of $R-$modules. We can even consider the category $\text{Kom}(C)$ whose objects are the complexes of $R-$modules and the morphisms are the equivalence class of the morphisms in $\text{Com}(C).$
Consider a morphism in $\text{Com}(C),$
$$\phi^\bullet:M^\bullet\to N^\bullet$$
and let $\eta:K^\bullet\to M^\bullet$ be its kernel. I know that the homotopy category is not abelian, hence in general a morphism in this category cannot have a kernel, but I want to study the case in which $\overline{\phi}$ has its kernel. Suppose then that the kernel of $\overline{\phi}$ exists: is there any relationship with the kernel of the map $\phi?$ I would like to prove that this kernel is given by $\overline{\eta}: K^\bullet\to M^\bullet$ but I’m not sure if it is true and eventually I don’t know how to prove it. Is it true? In this case, how can this be proved? If it is false, is there another relationship?

Comment: What if $\phi$ is very far from an isomorphism, but it's a homotopy equivalence ? Then $\overline \phi$ will have a kernel ($0$), but it will a priori have no "relationship" with $\ker \phi$. (also note, for future reference, that "homotopy kernel" might mean something different than "kernel in the homotopy category")

Comment: So isn't there, in general, any relationship?

Comment: Well there is a canonical map from one to the other (try to find which !) but as I pointed out there's no reason this map should be nice

Comment: I think this canonical map is given by the universal property of kernels, but as you said I cannot say much about this map... I was studying the homotopy kernel of the map between the complexes that have, respectively, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in degree $0,$ and zero elsewhere, where the map is the projection in degree $0.$ I think that there is no kernel in the homotopy category: if my assertion is correct in this case, I can conclude easily, but I don’t know how to prove this fact. Can I say something in this specific case?